# DetailVeiw не отображает данные

Tags: django, python-3.5

В проекте Django в приложении posts имею модель:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`
```

В файле views.py прописано:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from posts.models import Post

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

post_detail.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title%}
    <h1>{{object.title}}</h1>
{% endblock%}


{% block content%}
    <p>{{object.text}}</p>
    <p>{{object.date}}</p>
{% endblock%}
```

и URLConf:
 `url(r'^index/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail')`

Когда в адресной строке пишу: localhost:8000/index/1, то выводится только базовый шаблон, но информации про пост на странице нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определен ли блок **content** в шаблоне 'base.html'?

Попробуйте заменить

```
{% block content%}
    <p>{{object.text}}</p>
    <p>{{object.date}}</p>
{% endblock%}
```

на

```
{% block content%}
    <p>test</p>
    <p>{{object.text}}</p>
    <p>{{object.date}}</p>
{% endblock%}
```

Появился ли параграф 'test' в шаблоне?

Comment: Да, блок определен, но параграф 'test' не появился, с блоком 'title' это тоже не сработало. Честно говоря, я не совсем понял как класс DetailVew определяет шаблон, который должен быть сгенерирован, просто в официальной документации не нашел упоминаний о том, что это нужно где-то указывать.

Comment: @igormalyga название шаблона определяется названием модели и названием класса, в вашем случае полный путь до шаблона: `$TEMPLATE_DIR$/posts/post_detail.html`. Попробуйте определить путь к шаблону самостоятельно, добавив после `model = Post` строку `template_name = 'new_template.html'`, где **new_template.html** - название файла шаблона. Затем перейдите по URL'у и в сообщении об ошибке вы увидите в какой директории он пытается найти этот шаблон. Переместите свой в ту папку и переименуйте его.

Comment: нашел ошибку, после того как строка в URLConf была изменена с 
`url(r'^index/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail')`
 на `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail')`
Все заработало, однако я не понимаю, почему в прежнем состоянии ссылка была нерабочей?

Comment: @Igormalyga Скорее всего дело в порядке URL'ов. Ссылка проверяется по порядку сверху-вниз и как только регулярка совпадает - оно выдергивает представление. Можете попробовать переставить ваш первый вариант в самый верх паттернов и попробовать снова.